# call another function in a main function of javascript

Tags: javascript, html

```
    <script>
            function checkName(){
                var tmpName = document.getElementById("name");
                if( tmpName.value.length == 0 ){
                    alert( "Name cannot be empty" );
                    return false;
                }
                else
                    return true;
            }


            function confirmForm( formObj ){
                var nameBool = new Boolean();
                var errorName = "";


                nameBool = checkName();

                if( nameBool == false )
                    errorName = "Invalid data in input name !";

                return window.alert( "You have this error : \n " + errorName + "\n" + errorID ); 
            }

</script>
<form name=reviewform onsubmit="return confirmForm(reviewForm)" method=POST >
            <p>Name : <input type="text" id="name" ></p>

            <p>ID   : <input type="text" id="id" ></p>

            <input type="submit" value="Click here!">
</form>
```

my problem is why my function cannot run ??? isn't something wrong? can any senior teach me where the place i wrong at??

i already editited and plus that form name and the function how it's work

i don't know isn't my implementation wrong or what

Comment: What function doesn't run? How do you know it doesn't run? How have you attempted to debug it?

Comment: In the piece of code given, you are just defining two functions, not calling any of them. Could you be more specific ?

Comment: Did a error message occured in the error console of Firefox, Chrome, Safari?

Comment: no error message. just the script cannot run as well

Answer (score 1):

Both functions, though they need some work, and you clearly need to brush up on your JS knowledge, *can* run, you just have to call them. As it stands, you've just defined 2 functions. Nothing else.

Other issues, line/line:

```
//second line:
var tmpName = document.getElementById("name");
```

Here, you can't be sure this element is already leaded, perhaps the DOM isn't ready yet, so be careful, just wrap your entire code in a handler:

```
window.onload = function()
{
    //your code here, this gets executed after the page is fully loaded
};
```

Next, [don't think of JS as some sort of Java-for-browsers, it's a completely different animal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16376476/how-would-a-dom-less-statically-typed-ahead-of-time-compiled-javascipt-code-com/16377049#16377049). Stuff like:

```
var nameBool = new Boolean();
var errorName = "";
```

Is best written as declaring variables, but not assigning anything:

```
var nameBool, errorName;
```

If you want to be sure the nameBool is a boolean, just assign like so:

```
nameBool = !!checkName();//double bang
```

It also looks like you're trying to validate a form or handle a submit event of sorts. Why not use `addEventListener` for that? or, if you insist:

```
document.getElementById('formId').onsubmit = function(e)
{
    //get event object:
    e = e || window.event;
    //this references form, as does (e.target || e.srcElement), you can access the elements it contains, and check them one by one
};
```